# How to add percentage value in faceted barplot (qplot/ggplot/R)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data that looks like [this](http://dpaste.com/1269939/plain/):

```
ENSG00000211521 MIR665 x 89
....
ENSG00000207793 MIR432 y 50
....
```

What I want to do is to make a bar plot and 
add the 'percentage within population' on every bar. 
For example the value category 'y' with value 100, 
has the percentage 45.6 (132/289) this is because 
there are 132 of the one-hundreds and the total 
population is 289 **(for each "x" and "y"**).

In the end I'd like to have a plot that looks roughly like this:
[image]

But I'm stuck with the following code. What's the right way do it?

```
library(ggplot2)
dat.m <- read.delim("http://dpaste.com/1269939/plain/",sep="")
colnames(dat.m) <- c("ensg","mirna_hgc","variable","value")
qplot(value,data=dat.m, geom="bar", binwidth=1, origin=-0.05, xlim=c(50,100),ylim=c(0,75), facets=variable~.,main="")+
xlab("Value")+
ylab("Frequency")+
theme(legend.position="none")
```

**Update: computing the percentage**

The percentage in the graph above can be obtain with this code.
But somehow I couldn't find a way to include them into the qplot:

```
dat.m <- read.delim("http://dpaste.com/1269939/plain/",sep="")
colnames(dat.m) <- c("ensg","mirna_hgc","variable","value")
# the following steps can be applied for "x"
y <- subset(dat.m,dat.m$variable=="y")
y.df <- data.frame(table(y$value))
y.df$percentage <- ((y.df$Freq)/sum(y.df$Freq) * 100)
y.df
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding labels to ggplot bar chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653268/adding-labels-to-ggplot-bar-chart)

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386005/r-stacked-percentage-bar-plot-with-percentage-of-binary-factor-and-labels-with

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
qplot(value,data=dat.m, geom="bar", binwidth=1, origin=-0.05, xlim=c(50,100),ylim=c(0,75), facets=variable~.,main="")+
xlab("Value")+
ylab("Frequency")+
theme(legend.position="none") +
stat_bin(aes(label = sprintf("%.02f %%", ..count../sum(..count..)*100)),
     geom="text")
```

Some questions related:

[Rounding % Labels on bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516861/rounding-labels-on-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

[ggplot: showing % instead of counts in charts of categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/ggplot-showing-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables)

Comment: Hi thanks. But I couldn't get the percentage right. It gave me 10.9% instead of ~45%. How can I modify your code?

Comment: you can change `sum(..count..)*100` for `28900` which is your total population to figure out if the issue is due to the total count